# Adding custom attributes to matplotlib Figure and Axes instances: ill-advised?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I noticed that I can add my own attributes to `matplotlib.axes.Axes()` and `matplotlib.figure.Figure()` instances. For instance,

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.foo = 'bar'
```

In practical terms, I might like to add a basemap instance to an axes object using something like

```py
import mpl_toolkits.basemap as basemap    
ax.basemap = basemap.Basemap('mollweide', ax=ax)
```

So that I can add geographical features in a more object-oriented, intuitive way. Is this a documented/reliable feature of these objects, or is it accidental? In other words, can I "safely" use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [example](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/custom_figure_class.html) you can add any new property for custom Figure class. However for Axes class such task is more complicated. You have to make own Axes class

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Subplot
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap   

# custom Figure class with foo property  
class MyFigure(Figure):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.foo = kwargs.pop('foo', 'bar')
        Figure.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

# custom Axes class  
class MyAxes(Subplot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAxes, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # add my axes 
    @staticmethod
    def from_ax(ax=None, fig=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if ax is None:
            if fig is None: fig = figure(facecolor='w', edgecolor='w')
            ax = MyAxes(fig, 1, 1, 1, *args, **kwargs)
            fig.add_axes(ax)
        return ax

# test run
# custom figure
fig = figure(FigureClass=MyFigure, foo='foo')
print (type(fig), fig.foo)

# add to figure custom axes
ax = MyAxes.from_ax(fig=fig)
print (type(fig.gca()))

# create Basemap instance and store it to 'm' property
ax.m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119, llcrnrlat=22, urcrnrlon=-64, urcrnrlat=49, 
 projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=45, lon_0=-95, resolution='c')
ax.m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.25)
ax.m.drawcountries(linewidth=.25)
ax.m.fillcontinents(color='coral', lake_color='aqua')

print (ax.m)
show()
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.MyFigure'> foo
<class '__main__.MyAxes'>
<mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap object at 0x107fc0358>
```

[image]

However my opinion is that you do not need to make `m` property of axes class. You have to call all functions according to basemap in custom axes class i.e. in `__init___` (or make special method like `set_basemap`).

Comment: Thanks, this was extremely helpful. I have a useful auto-formatting function for the types of figures I typically make, and will instead make that definition a method of a `Figure` subclass (much cleaner). And you're right, I probably won't bother subclassing axes and will just do the coordinate conversions manually.

I would use `cartopy` (which is much more object-oriented/intuitive), but unfortunately `basemap` is still way, way more feature rich (for example, longitude/latitude labels in `cartopy` are pretty much unusable).